# Split int into char array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I have an int, and I need to split it to a char array, so 2 chars in each array position. After that, I need to do the opposite process. This is the best I could come up with, but I still couldn't make it work. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
    int length = 10968;
    int bytesNeeded = sizeof(length) / 2;
    char *controlPacket = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*bytesNeeded);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesNeeded; i++)
    {
        controlPacket[i] = (length >> (8* i));
    }
    int newSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesNeeded; i++)
    {
        newSize += (controlPacket[i] << (8 * i));
    }
    printf("Newsize is: %d\n", newSize);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` should be `sizeof(char)` -- there's always one less `*` than the type you're assigning to.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the result should be?

Comment: `char *controlPacket = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*bytesNeeded);` -> `char *controlPacket = malloc(sizeof(*controlPacket)*bytesNeeded);`

Comment: Why do you divide by 2?

Comment: If the length field in the control packet needs to be 2 bytes long, set `bytesNeeded` to 2, not `sizeof(length) / 2`.

Comment: @Barmar did that, same result

Comment: @Barmar it returns Newsize is: 10712

Comment: @klutt still same result

Comment: You should generally use `unsigned` if you're performing bitwise operations.

Comment: What is the expected contents of `controlPacket`?

Comment: You need to mask the result of shifting: `length >> (8*i) & 0xff`

Comment: @Barmar i've tried that aswell, still 10712

Comment: I'll re-ask klutt's question: why are you dividing by 2? You're only processing half of the number.

Comment: @Barmar in this case, it should be 0xd8 in the first element, and 0x2a in the second. in the end, newSize sould be equal to length

Comment: @Barmar for some reason, if you run it, you'll se that bytesNeeded is double of what is actually need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variables that you're performing bitwise operations on to `unsigned`, and also mask the result of shifting before assigning to the array. Otherwise, you get overflow, which causes incorrect results (maybe undefined behavior, I'm not sure).

You also shouldn't divide `sizeof(length)` by 2. It will work for values that only use the low order half of the number, but not for larger values; e.g. if you use `length = 1096800;` the result will be `48824`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
    unsigned int length = 10968;
    int bytesNeeded = sizeof(length);
    unsigned char *controlPacket = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*bytesNeeded);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesNeeded; i++)
    {
        controlPacket[i] = (length >> (8* i) & 0xff);
    }
    unsigned int newSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesNeeded; i++)
    {
        newSize += (controlPacket[i] << (8 * i));
    }
    printf("Newsize is: %d\n", newSize);
    free(controlPacket);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been hitting my head against the wall over this. Marked it as correct

Comment: I just updated the answer, you shouldn't divide by 2, you'll get the wrong result for large values of `length`.